# How can I uninstall Ruby on ubuntu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, uninstallation

How can I uninstall Ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-02) [i486-linux]
on ubuntu?
 Need to reinstall - please help

Comment: Helpful similar question on the ubuntu stackexchange:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/95/completely-remove-ruby-rails-gems

Comment: Using `which -a ruby` I found out my ruby installation could be found in `/usr/bin/ruby` Well that's not exactly the case. I went to `/usr/bin` and listed all the folders/files in the `bin` directory` using `ls -ln`, and found out `/usr/bin/ruby` is just the alias. The actually path to the installation directory has the version appended, for me it was `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1`. I was successfully able to uninstall ruby using `sudo apt remove ruby1.9.1`

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This command should do the trick (provided that you installed it using a dpkg-based packet manager):

```
aptitude purge ruby
```

Comment: thanks for your response. It didn't sloved this problem. I execute this command and check ruby -v. it still show ruby 1.8.7

Comment: $ sudo aptitude purge ruby
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 0B of archives. After unpacking 0B will be used.

Comment: $ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2010-04-19 patchlevel 253) [i686-linux], MBARI 0x8770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2010.02

Comment: It seems like aptitude did not find the package `ruby` on your system. Execute `dpkg -l | grep ruby` for a list of installed ruby-related packages. For example `ruby1.8`.

Comment: yes. I execute this command. this is result libopenssl-ruby, ruby-enterprise  1.8.7-2010.02, ruby1.8 1.8.6.111-2ubuntu1...

Comment: Then simply execute `aptitude purge ruby1.8` to remove that package.

Comment: I suggest that you add `sudo ` in your answer for lazy "copiers/pasters" like the person that wrote my comment.

Answer (score 72):

Run the following command from your terminal:

`sudo apt-get purge ruby`

Usually works well for me.

(caution: this can delete essential system files related to GRUB and other components)

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge ruby*` will remove grub! Be careful.

Comment: Ok, I have never seen that happen. I will look out for that :)

Comment: I did sudo apt-get purge ruby* but when I type ruby -v it shows ruby 1.9.2

Comment: @Francois I think you should use sudo apt-get remove ruby1.9.2 ? I have 1.9.1 installed and it works

Comment: yea seemed to do the trick, thanks, I keep tryping uninstall instead of remove :)

Comment: In my case also `sudo apt-get autoremove` was needed after `sudo apt-get remove ruby1.9.3`

Comment: @sestevez I accidently did `sudo apt-get purge ruby*` and I haven't turned off my system. Can I install grub and update grub

Answer (score 23):

At first find out where ruby is?
then

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
rm -rf /usr/lib/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/local/bin/gem
rm -f /usr/bin/gem
```

Answer (score 16):

I have tried many include `sudo apt-get purge ruby` , `sudo apt-get remove ruby` and `sudo aptitude purge ruby`, both with and without '*' at the end. But none of them worked, it may be I've installed more than one version of ruby.

Finally, when I tried `sudo apt-get purge ruby1.9`(with the version), then it works.

Answer (score 13):

Run the following command on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove ruby
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is what `sudo apt-get purge ruby*`  removed relating to `GRUB` for me:

```
grub-pc 
grub-gfxpayload-lists
grub2-common
grub-pc-bin 
grub-common
```

Answer (score 4):

On Lubuntu, I just tried apt-get purge ruby* and as well as removing ruby, it looks like this command tried to remove various things to do with GRUB, which is a bit worrying for next time I want to reboot my computer. I can't yet say if any damage has really been done.

Comment: The same happened to me, but it gives you the clue on what packages yo have to uninstall to remove ruby. So just remove all the packages the apt suggested, except for the obvious ones you don't want to remove, like grub, and you are done.

Answer (score 3):

If you used `rbenv` to install it, you can use

```
rbenv versions
```

to see which versions you have installed.

Then, use the uninstall command:

```
rbenv uninstall [-f|--force] <version>
```

for example:

```
rbenv uninstall 2.4.0  # Uninstall Ruby 2.4.0
```

If you installed Rails, it will be removed, too.

Comment: Where in the question did the OP mention rbenv?

Answer (score 1):

Why you are removing old version of the ruby?

> rvm install 2.4.2 // version of ruby u need to insatll
>   rvm use 2.4.2 --default // set ruby version you want use by default

Using rvm you can install multiple ruby version in the system

Please follow below steps install ruby using rvm

```
sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable 
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm install 2.4.2 
rvm use 2.4.2 --default 
ruby -v
```

The installation step will change for different Ubuntu version

For more info,

https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/14.04

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the make install software when make uninstall invalid.

- make install will create file ***'.installed.list'***
- Choose to clean up the files described in ***.installed.list*** (need to be careful if you have multiple versions)
- Case: `ruby2.4` switch to `ruby2.3`, thinking directly delete all ruby software, and then re-make install 2.3, see: Ruby # Installation Guide
- `make install -> .installed.list`
- see .installed.list file, delete all install files.

‌

```
rm -rf /usr/local/include/ruby-*
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
rm /usr/local/bin/erb /usr/local/bin/gem /usr/local/bin/irb /usr/local/bin/rdoc /usr/local/bin/ri /usr/local/bin/ruby
rm /usr/local/share/man/man1/erb.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/irb.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/ri.1 /usr/local/share/man/man1/ruby.1
rm /usr/local/lib/libruby-static.a
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ruby-*
which ruby
pkg-config --list-all|grep ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sudo apt remove ruby`