# how to uninstall ruby

Tags: ruby

How do I uninstall my system installed ruby?

I am on ubuntu 11.1. I have already installed rvm, but it seems 1.8 is conflicting. How do I remove the existing ruby installation and cleanly install ruby back ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: Theres already a previous post about this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957730/how-can-i-uninstall-ruby-on-ubuntu

Comment: Thanks. Can u post it as an answer, so that I can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby rubygems
```

It can remove ruby which installed by apt-get

Answer (score 1):

try to use always rvm to install ruby.It is a good habbit and easy to mange follow this link

```
   http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/
```

then simply install any ruby version by this command

```
   rvm install 1.9.2
```

if remove this ruby version then use

```
   rvm remove 1.9.2
```

if you don't have rvm install then use this command

```
  aptitude purge ruby
```

Comment: I uninstalled ruby, and installed it back through rvm. However when I do 'gem install xxx' it still goes to the dir on file system and not under rvm. How do I remedy it?