# Un-install RVM, Ruby, Ruby gem and rails in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

What is the best way to remove RVM, Ruby, Ruby gem and rails in Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: `rvm implode`. Assuming: you installed Ruby using rvm. You installed ruby gems into (any) rvm gemset.

Comment: @Ganeshkunwar, I guess you installed ruby using apt-get(not using rvm). So remove ruby from system using `aptitude purge ruby`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first find where ruby is? then

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
rm -rf /usr/lib/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/local/bin/gem
rm -f /usr/bin/gem
```

Have a try. may it will help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rm -rf ~/.rvm` to remove RVM. If there is a separate version of ruby installed you'll need to `sudo apt-get remove ruby1.x.x` depending on the version.

Comment: `rails` is a gem and can be uninstalled with `gem uninstall rails`.

Comment: rails is removed, but ruby is still not removed.

Comment: Type `ruby -v` to see what version of ruby is installed and then use `sudo apt-get remove ruby1.x.x` where 1.x.x is the version. For example if `ruby -v` shows 1.9.2 then do `sudo apt-get remove ruby1.9.2`

Comment: You can use `dpkg -l | grep ruby` to see the name of the ruby package directly. See here for more help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957730/how-can-i-uninstall-ruby-on-ubuntu