# installation issue ruby2.0 in ubuntu

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I am using `Ubuntu13.0`. just tried to install `Ruby2.0` using the [`Link`](https://gist.github.com/ngauthier/5039249). After the installation when I did `ruby -v`,found:

```
kirti@kirti-Aspire-5733Z:~$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i686-linux]
```

I just removed `1.8.7` using [`How can I uninstall Ruby on ubuntu?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957730/how-can-i-uninstall-ruby-on-ubuntu)

please help me to re-install Ruby2.0.

Comment: what will you get if you write '$ which ruby' in bash ?

Comment: @MateuszCzerwiński I want to install ruby2.0. How to do so? please guide me. I uninstall ruby1.8.7

Comment: Maybe this link will be usefull - http://rubysource.com/installing-ruby-with-rvm-on-ubuntu/ or try read sth about rvm (ruby version manager) https://rvm.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it using [`Ubuntu 13.04 install RVM with Ruby 2.0.0-p0 , Rails 4.0.0 beta1`](https://gist.github.com/pcjpcj2/5443017). This is an awesome link.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the path to `ruby2.0` to environment variables in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/ruby_2_bin_path/:$PATH
```