# How to remove Ruby from Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to remove Ruby, so I try this. How can I remove this?

```
sudo apt-get autoremove ruby
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'ruby' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 534 not upgraded.

here@jaskaran:/$ whereis ruby
    ruby: /usr/bin/ruby /usr/lib/ruby /usr/bin/X11/ruby /usr/share/man/man1/ruby.1.gz
here@jaskaran:/$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
```

Comment: Do you have rvm installed on your system ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Ubuntu...?

Use this to find out what executable you're running:

```
$ which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Use this to find out what it actually is:

```
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

Use this to find out what package it belongs to:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/ruby1.8
ruby1.8: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

Use this to uninstall that:

```
$ apt-get purge ruby1.8
```

> **Note**: If you have installed Ruby using Version/Environment managers like [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [Rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) then this method is not gonna work because Rubies will be installed as scripts not packages.

Comment: Now Pleas help me to install rmv on Ubuntu 12.10 How to install rmv with ruby and rails ?

Comment: deep this is for Ubantu 13.10 I have 12.04 OR 12.10 I want to install in both please tell me for 12.04 and 12.10

Comment: Please stop, and go read the instructions at the rvm home page; they are quite extensive and well-written. Ask if you have any *specific* problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22754012/i-have-run-command-rvm-intall-and-get-errro

Comment: @user3425009 for 12.10 check http://goo.gl/lpkeIi and follow the instructions carefully

Answer (score 8):

If you used `rbenv` to install it, you can use

```
rbenv versions
```

to see which versions you have installed.

Then, use the uninstall command:

```
rbenv uninstall [-f|--force] <version>
```

for example:

```
rbenv uninstall 2.4.0  # Uninstall Ruby 2.4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Ruby using RVM then the following command will completely remove RVM installed directory:

> ```
> rvm implode
> ```

Running this command will ask for your confirmation to delete the `.rvm` directory.

After it completes deleting the `.rvm` directory, you get the following message which is worth notable:

> Note you may need to manually remove /etc/rvmrc and ~/.rvmrc if they
>   exist still.
>
> Please check all .bashrc .bash_profile .profile and .zshrc for RVM
>   source lines and delete or comment out if this was a Per-User
>   installation.

Answer (score -5):

At first find out where ruby is? then

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
rm -rf /usr/lib/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/bin/ruby
rm -f /usr/local/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/bin/irb
rm -f /usr/local/bin/gem
rm -f /usr/bin/gem
```

Or you can try this one also.

```
aptitude purge ruby
```

Comment: Impatient, are we? Because removing libraries installed through package system should be removed through the package system. In addition to introducing inconsistency, it also misses quite a bit of files (e.g. the documentation files). At the time of the downvote, you did not have the `aptitude` alternative (and it's downvote-worthy anyway as long as the `rm` bit stands).

Comment: Ok but i am doing work and try to update the solution and provide better answer to him, so you should wait for some time to downvote. And also i know that downvote is useful for user to check the good answer and bed answer as well.

Comment: Isn't this answer a copy-paste of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11536137/1420197), more or less?

Comment: Yes its copy paste :D