# I have run command rvm intall and get error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I want to install rvm, but I get this error. How do I remove this error?

```
root@jaskaran:/# ruby -v
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: apt-get install <selected package>
//--------------------------------------------------------------


   here@jaskaran:/$ rvm install 2.1.0
        Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
        No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/12.10/i386/ruby-2.1.0.
        Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
        Checking requirements for ubuntu.
        Installing requirements for ubuntu.
        Updating system................
        Error running 'requirements_debian_update_system ruby-2.1.0',
        showing last 15 lines of /home/zapbuild/.rvm/log/1396242152_ruby-2.1.0/update_system.log
        ++ case "${TERM:-dumb}" in
        ++ case "$1" in
        ++ [[ -t 2 ]]
        ++ return 1
        ++ printf %b 'There has been error while updating '\''apt-get'\'', please give it some time and try again later.
        For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
            /etc/apt/sources.list
            /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list
        \n'
        There has been error while updating 'apt-get', please give it some time and try again later.
        For 404 errors check your sources configured in:
            /etc/apt/sources.list
            /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list

        ++ return 100
        Requirements installation failed with status: 100.
```

Thanks

Comment: how did u install rvm

Comment: Ubntu 12.04, this why := http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Comment: the steps to install rvm have reduced significantly now..that blog was written in 2010

Comment: do you have any reference blog to do this

Comment: Last updated: Friday 3rd January 2014 --- http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

Comment: check out this http://rvm.io/rvm/install

Answer (score 0):

To install rvm run this.

```
$ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash
```

Or in case you just want to update your rvm with the available ruby list, use **rvm get stable**. Now install ruby using `rvm install ruby-2.1.0` or `rvm install 2.1.0`. This should fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on ubuntu 14.04 today.And I removed broken source in source.list and source.list.d/*.And it just worked fine for me.

After that you can run

```
sudo apt-get update
rvm requirements
```

Hope that is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Remove PPA sources from software setting and run these commands in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties

sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev

curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc

rvm install 2.1.3

rvm use 2.1.3 --default

ruby -v

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nodejs

gem install rails

rails -v
```