# error in uninstalling Ruby from UBUNTU 14.0.4 LTS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, uninstallation

I have made some mistake in installing Ruby and and now I'm trying to uninstall it ([How to remove ruby from ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753785/how-to-remove-ruby-from-ubuntu)) but it's giving the following error. I tried with `sudo apt-get purge ruby` but still couldn't uninstall. It shows ruby is not installed but I did check and confirm that it is installed in the location `/usr/local/bin/ruby`. please help me to uninstall Ruby and RVM from my machine.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]

$ sudo apt-get purge ruby 1.8.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libhdf5-mpich2-1.8.7' for regex '1.8.7'
Note, selecting 'libhdf5-1.8.7' for regex '1.8.7'
Note, selecting 'libghc-utility-ht-prof-0.0.5.1-87764' for regex '1.8.7'
Note, selecting 'libhdf5-openmpi-1.8.7' for regex '1.8.7'
Note, selecting 'libhdf5-serial-1.8.7' for regex '1.8.7'
Note, selecting 'libghc-utility-ht-dev-0.0.5.1-87764' for regex '1.8.7'
Note, selecting 'libghc-utility-ht-dev' instead of 'libghc-utility-ht-dev-0.0.5.1-87764'
Note, selecting 'libghc-utility-ht-prof' instead of 'libghc-utility-ht-prof-0.0.5.1-87764'
Package 'libhdf5-1.8.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libhdf5-serial-1.8.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libhdf5-mpich2-1.8.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libhdf5-openmpi-1.8.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ruby' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 567 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed the `ruby` directory from `home` directory and followed the below steps...

```
$ whereis ruby
ruby: /usr/local/bin/ruby /usr/local/lib/ruby

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]

$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/ruby
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/ruby
$ ruby -v
bash: /usr/local/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

finally it got uninstalled !!
Thanks to [Rick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2524123/rick)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove ruby completely,

```
sudo apt-get purge ruby rubygems
```

Or you can follow this steps below,

Use this to find out what it is

```
$ readlink -f /usr/local/bin/ruby

/usr/local/bin/ruby1.8.7
```

Use this to find out what package is using:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/ruby1.8.7
ruby1.8: /usr/local/bin/ruby1.8.7
```

And use this to install,

```
$ apt-get purge ruby1.8.7
```

Comment: Thanks rick but I'm not able to do this

Comment: $ ruby -v    =ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: $ dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/ruby    =dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/ruby

Comment: $ sudo apt-get purge ruby1.8.7   =E: Unable to locate package ruby1.8.7

Comment: @Nani try this one `$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/ruby1.8.7`

Comment: sorry to say that even this too didn't help me

Comment: $ dpkg -S /usr/bin/ruby1.8.7    =dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/bin/ruby1.8.7

Comment: $ dpkg -S /usr/local/bin/ruby1.8.7    =dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/bin/ruby1.8.7

Comment: @Nani are you using rvm? if yes then use this `rvm unistall 1.8.7`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80263/discussion-between-rick-and-nani).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rvm, then you can uninstall ruby 1.8.7 using the command

```
rvm unistall 1.8.7
```

and then you uninstall the rvm using the command

```
rvm implode
```