# Why can't bundler find rake when it's obviously installed?

Tags: ruby, rake, bundler, redmine, bitnami

I'm trying to migrate a version of Redmine from backup to a new server; I'm migrating from Redmine 3.2.3 to 3.3.0. I installed the new version of Redmine (from Bitnami Stack) on my new server and everything loads properly. When I move my old database into the new version, I have to run

`bundle exec rake db:migrate`

to migrate my database. But... bundler can't find rake somehow even though `gem list` shows it clearly installed. Can I force bundler to use the version of rake that I have installed that it says I don't?

[image]

I should mention I've done no customization at all, haven't installed any gems, or changed ruby versions or done anything. This is out of the box Redmine.

I noticed after I made the question that I had two versions of rake installed. I removed both and reinstalled rake 11.1.2 and have the same problem.

Comment: Can you run `bundle list`? Do you have rake on the list?

Comment: I couldn't run `bundle` anything. I may have figured it out (Ruby versions/locations).... I have to do a few more things on this server to test and I'll answer if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using the wrong `ruby` binary. Note that, the installers for Bitnami Stacks are completely self-contained and run independently of the rest of the software or libraries installed on your system.

Also, taking a look at the screenshots you have shared, you were using ruby 1.9.3 when you have executed `ruby -v` and the Redmine Bitnami Stacks uses ruby 2.1.9. Probably this is the reason of the issue you are having.

If you want to use the ruby (and the other components) shipped with the Bitnami Stack you need to run the following command:

```
cd *INSTALLDIR*
./use_redmine
```

This command will open a new console session with the environment configured to use the stack.

Comment: I don't know what this `./use_redmine` is, but your answer was basically what the problem was. I'm going to answer with the full description of what I had to do, but I'll mark yours because it's technically correct.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things:

- ruby gems available via `gem list`
- ruby gems availbale via bundler

When you are using `bundle` then bundler is looking for gem from `Gemfile`. You can have multiple gems installed in your system, but when you are using Gemfile then gem version will be taken from `Gemfile.lock`

Summing up:

- `$ bundle exec rake ...`

require to have rake gem inside Gemfile

- `$ rake ...`

it will take the newest version of rake gem installed in system

I hope it helps you.

Comment: The rake gem was in the Gemfile. It kept saying it couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally got my Redmine upgraded:

A version of ruby outside of the one provided by Bitnami somehow got installed on this machine as well as another version of bundler. The first thing I did was uninstall the `apt-get` version of bundler. I had to manually remove `/usr/bin/bundler` and `/usr/bin/bundle` for `$ which bundle` to stop finding bundler even after the removal.

I saw that the Bitnami stack's ruby was version 2.1.x but found Ruby 1.9.3 was installed to `/usr/bin/ruby1.9.3/` with `$ which ruby`. I took [the commands from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753859/386703) and removed that version of Ruby.

Running `$ ruby -v` now gave me nothing as Ruby wasn't installed anymore (even though it was in the Bitnami stack). Bitnami's Ruby then had to be (re?)added to my path  in `~/.profile`. `$ ruby -v` now gives me the correct version.

`$ gem list` was no longer telling me that rake was installed. I tried running `$ bundle install` where `Gemfile` is but was complaining about `mime-types` being locked at a lower version and wouldn't do anything. I got around that with `$ bundle update` but then ran into the infamous `nokogiri` problem where it complains that everything required by `nokogiri` isn't installed.

Since I'd dealt with this before (many many times) I went over to [the Nokogiri Website's install page](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html) and followed the instructions for troubleshooting on Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch
sudo apt-get install ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

and now `$ bundle update` worked on my `Gemfile`. Redmine upgraded and my users are about as happy as users can get.