# How to uninstall/delete older ruby version and keep newer. I have two version of ruby installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu, rvm

I had ruby `2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x86_64-linux]` I had to upgrade it to `ruby 2.3.1` through RVM because i wanted to upgrade rails. After upgrading ruby to (2.3.1) and then rails to (4.2.6) when i close terminal and re-open, it again use `ruby 2.2.3p173` which is older version. and every time I have to run below command s to make it work on `ruby 2.3.1`

```
$ source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

$ type rvm | head -n 1

$ rvm --default use 2.3.1
```

[image: Check this out]

Is there any way I do not have to run this process every time and by default I can use new version of `ruby 2.3.1` ?

Comment: If your default isn't sticking there's something wrong with your `rvm` install.

Comment: what possibly could have went wrong ? and how would I fix it ?@tadman

Comment: Reinstalling it is a good first step, you can do that in-place without breaking anything. Second step is to see why `rvm versions` doesn't show the correct one being activated on login. `--default` should set that.

Comment: What is the value for GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME in your environment variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I uninstall Ruby on ubuntu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957730/how-can-i-uninstall-ruby-on-ubuntu)

Comment: It only provides information on how to delete ruby. In my case I need to use `ruby 2.3.1` as by default in stead of `ruby 2.2.3` thus it is not duplicate question. @AniketShivamTiwari

Comment: Until you get GEM_PATH and GEM_HOME set properly you will have to reset your default Ruby version -- Ruby is a gem.

Comment: This does not appear to be a duplicate of the nominated exemplar, which asks how to uninstall the system Ruby.  Uninstalling the system Ruby may or may not be the solution (or part of the solution) to this problem, but we don't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little misleading. You have a system installation of ruby and installed rvm and another ruby version with that - and now you want to have sourced rvm per default.

To not need to do `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm` anymore, you just put that into your `~/.bash_profile` (where it maybe already was put automatically) and ensure your terminal is a login shell.

For Gnome Terminal you click "Profile Preferences", and choose "Run command as login shell" in Tab "Title and Command".

If I did not figure correct shell configuration, follow instructions here: https://rvm.io/rvm/basics

*Sorry information there are to many and system specific, to copy all here.*

Comment: Thank you..!! I followed all the steps and it worked. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly sudo apt-get purge ruby

And if you want to use a select version of ruby then try  rvm use ruby 'version' .It will select the version you want to use for ruby

Comment: Please have a look at my question again. `rvm use` will not work in here. again have a look in image I provided in question

Comment: did you try the first command i told you sudo apt-get purge ruby

Comment: yes I did both and it gives same error rvm use will not work.