# Ubuntu files get deleted when I use sudo apt-get remove ruby

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I gave the command `sudo apt-get remove ruby 2.0.0` in Ubuntu 16, but it started deleting all the files including Ubuntu files and now I am not able to switch it back on, it's just showing a black screen!

How can I restore my system to a bootable state?

Comment: What do you mean ubuntu files?

Comment: This question is better suited on https://askubuntu.com/. In any case, please add more details about what actually happened, preferably with the copied output of your commands.

Comment: If your system is corrupted. It if often easier to restart from installing the OS. In that case, just save the home directory in some other media before erasing the whole volume.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby 2.0.0
```

It work as

```
sudo apt-get remove ruby && sudo apt-get remove 2.0.0
```

If you want remove all ruby files read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957730/how-can-i-uninstall-ruby-on-ubuntu)

Also use ruby version meneger for remove single ruby version/ For example:

```
rvm uninstall VERSION_NUMBER
```

For restoring ubuntu read [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1825888)